# Dependency Injection on AuthorizationOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am creating an authorization rule/policy for my ASP.NET 5 MVC application. Creating it was straightforward and pretty easy to do, and it is working (with my basic tests). However, I now need to get my data context into the requirement.

I created a constructor in my IAuthorizationRequirement implementation which takes a `MyContext` object which implements `DbContext`.

I am registering the IAuthorizationRequirement like so in my `Startup.cs` file.

```
services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options => 
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowProfileManagement", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(
            new AllowProfileManagementRequirement(new MyRepository(new MyContext()))));
    });
```

Unfortunately, when my rule runs, `MyContext` is unaware of the connection strings which are used like so (farther up in `Startup.cs`):

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<MemorialContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

I am using DI for these types otherwise (and it is working).

```
services.AddTransient<MyRepository>(
        provider => new MyRepository(provider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>()));
```

I know what I am doing is not right, but I don't see how to make this right so that DI is being leveraged across everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's how it always works. Post the question, and the answer comes shortly after. Here's how for those who may come across my question.

```
services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options => 
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowProfileManagement", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(
            services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService< AllowProfileManagementRequirement>()));
    });
```

Comment: When I implement this, I get the `no service for type has been registered` on the AllowProfileManagementRequirement. See my original question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203771/how-to-clear-cachekey-in-separate-instance-of-imemorycache