# Dependency Injection on AuthorizationOptions Requirement in DotNet Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have a .NET core project and am trying to create a custom policy using AuthorizationOptions as shown in the documentation located here:

[ASP.NET.Core Authorization - Dependency Injection in requirement handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection)

The examples show setting up an authorization requirement with 1 parameter - a simple int value.  My custom requirement requires a string parameter as well as a DbContext object.  I want to inject the DbContext into the requirement's constructor at runtime.  I am using the Autofac container.  I'm not sure how I can achieve this - have tried several approaches and nothing is working so far.

Here is my custom requirement:

```cs
public UserNameRequirement(string username, MyDbContext context)
{
    _userName = username;
    _dbContext = context;
}
```

When setting up the authorization options in Startup.cs  ConfigureServices method the documentation shows you register this like so:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "UserNamePolicy",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserNameRequirement("admin", ** want to resolve and inject my DbContext here **)));
}
```

I am not sure how to achieve this.  I've seen this post which is a similar question but it's using ASP.NET 5 and that syntax doesn't work with .net core:

[Dependency Injection on AuthorizationOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470047/dependency-injection-on-authorizationoptions#)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the need for an instance of `MyDbContext` in the `UserNameRequirement` class?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OK, I'm going to make an assumption here, and that is that you need to inject an instance of `MyDbContext` in `UserNameRequirement` to perform the business logic.

If this is the case, then it means `UserNameRequirement` both holds the data - in your case the username - and does the authorization logic. An example of this in ASP.NET Core is the [`ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/7637f2ea44c7f296623615ecab0370048155958f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/Infrastructure/ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement.cs#L17).

The solution to this is to separate this into two classes - on one side the requirement that just holds the data associated with the requirement, on on the other side the authorization handler. As a note, even if we'll go through it, what I'm describing is available in the [official ASP.NET Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies).

So the requirement class could look something like:

```cs
public class UserNameRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public UserNameRequirement(string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public string UserName { get; }
}
```

and the handler class would be:

```cs
public class UserNameRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserNameRequirement>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    public UserNameRequirementHandler(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserNameRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userName = requirement.UserName;

        // Use _dbContext to perform business logic
    }
}
```

The next and last part is to register the handler in the container:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNameRequirementHandler>();
```

The effect of doing this is that you can now add your requirement to the policy without worrying about the `DbContext`:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "UserNamePolicy",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserNameRequirement("admin")));
}
```

Internally, ASP.NET will then resolve all the handlers associated with that requirement through the container, so the instance of `MyDbContext` will be available to you in the handler, allowing you to perform the business logic as you see fit.

Hopefully, my assumption is correct, and this helps you.

*Edit:*

Henry Roux made a good point in a comment below regarding the fact that if the `UserNameRequirementHandler` is registered as a singleton, then a single instance of `MyDbContext` will be used, and that could lead to issues. Make sure you register your authorization handlers with the appropriate lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the clear explanation I needed.

Comment: I'm interested in how successful this solution has held up to load testing and real-world production environments? The `UserNameRequirementHandler` is registered as a singleton, and this means that the `MyDbContext` that gets injected there is never refreshed. It is thus never disposed, the connection is never closed, and if you don't use the `AsNoTracking()` option, you'll find that data updated in the DB is never reported correctly when you read from that entity. Experienced any of this?

Comment: @HenkRoux that's a good point. I'll try to justify this by saying the answer was here to provide a way to use DI for requirements, not the one way to do it. I'll edit the answer to include your comments. cheers.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey what if I had multiple handlers that need DI? The snippet

`services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNameRequirementHandler>();`

clearly links all IAuthorizationHandlers to that single instance...

Comment: @zemien Not really, it links the `UserNameRequirementHandler` as **an** instance of `IAuthorizationHandler`, not as **the single** instance. The subtle difference is that you can register multiple types or instances against the same `IAuthorizationHandler` interface, and the framework will resolve all of them. I suggest that you read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies#authorization-handlers) for more information.

Comment: Could the AddSingleton be used to substitue in a new IOptions in here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/2b2aeee9f869ec43f65c188a66d9285858823628/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L42

Answer (score 1):

You can use also the GetRequiredService method:

```
public class ExampleRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<ExampleRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ExampleRequirement requirement)
    {
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = ((ActionContext)context.Resource).HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        // you can work with the users ...      

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```