# Role based authorization in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Identity and ExternalLogin

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, role-based-access-control

Im new to .NET Core and I'm trying to setup Role based authorization in a .NET Core 3.1 project. I believe I clicked on every tutorials and threads talking about it online. My problem is that it seems to be working very easily on the tutorials, but it doesn't work for me. According to tutorials I have found, all I would have to do is assign a role to a user in a database, then use `[Authorize(Roles="roleName")]` before a Controller's Action. When I do that I always get a 403 error for a user having the specified role. When I use `userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)`, I see that the user has the role. When I make a request to this action with [Authorize], it works when the user is logged in, as expected.

I checked in debug mode ClaimsPrincipal.Identity for the current user and I found out that `RoleClaimType = "role"`. I checked the claims of the current user and found out that it doesn't have a claim with a type "role". Is this how `[Authorize(Roles="...")]` works? Does it look a the claims? If so, how do I had a claim for the user's role? The only way for a user to login in this application is with a Google account. So how am I supposed to add a claim if they are managed by the Google login?

Here's my code in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
            Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

            options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
        })
        .AddIdentityServerJwt();

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    }
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
    });
}
```

Here's an exemple of an Action of a Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpGet("userinformations")]
public async Task<UserInformations> GetCurrentUserInformations()
{
    string strUserId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(strUserId);

    string[] roles = (await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)).ToArray();

    UserInformations userInfo = new UserInformations()
    {
        UserName = user.UserName,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
        Email = user.Email,
        Organization = user.idDefaultOrganisation.HasValue ? user.DefaultOrganization.OrganizationName : "",
        Claims = this.User.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type} : {c.Value}").ToArray(),
        Roles = roles
    };

    return userInfo;
}
```

When I make a request to this Action without [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")], I can see that the current user has the role Admin, but when I add it, I get a 403 error.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I'm missing one line somewhere or something like that because it all seems so simple in the tutorials I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a working solution. 
I tried adapting @MichaelShterenberg 's code using RequireAssertion, but I couldn't get it to work because I had to query my database and I was not able to use UserManager with this solution. 
I ended up finding a solution based on this part of his answer :

> You should probably create your own AuthorizationHandler that checks if the user is indeed Admin

I followed the answer of this thread : [Dependency Injection on AuthorizationOptions Requirement in DotNet Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423282/dependency-injection-on-authorizationoptions-requirement-in-dotnet-core?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption was correct, when you specify the `[Authorize(Roles = "<role>")]` attribute, ASP will create a `RolesAuthorizationRequirement` behind the scene.

Then the authorization handler will call `this.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(<role>)` to evaluate the policy.

In your case, the call is `this.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin")`

The method `User.IsInRole` will look into a claim named `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"` and compare its value to "Admin"

The ASP Authorization pipeline is not hooked to your UserManager logic, the basic API will only observe and validate the JWT token claims.

You should probably create your own AuthorizationHandler that checks if the user is indeed Admin

Or the less formal way using RequireAssertion :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Admininstrators", builder =>
{
    builder.RequireAssertion(async context =>
    {
        string strUserId = context.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(strUserId);
        string[] roles = (await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)).ToArray();
        return roles.Contains("Admin");
    };
});
```

```
[Authorize("Admininstrators")]
[HttpGet("userinformations")]
public async Task<UserInformations> GetCurrentUserInformations()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Now that I know it uses that claim, how do I had the claim base on the content of my database?

Comment: You have several ways to do this:
The most standard is to create your own AuthorizaionRequirement and AuthorizarionHandler and implement HandleRequirementAsync method. You can see how the ```RolesAuthorizationRequirement ``` is implemented https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b56f84131af2e1ece61241a016e191f5f2fe3fc0/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/RolesAuthorizationRequirement.cs

Then you define your own policy and add this requirement

Check this guide https://geeklearning.io/create-your-own-authorization-requirements-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Added a code sample in my answer using the quicker ```RequireAssertion``` solution

Comment: Thank you I will try this and mark it as an answer if it works, but do you think there is a way to add the "role" claim on user login in a way that I can use `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`. This way I would not need to make a new policy every time there is a new role in my database. Like during the authentication, there is a check in the database for the user's roles to add them to the claim

Comment: Although I'm sure there is someway to accomplish this, I would recommend against it.
1. You end up calling user manager on authentication, even when you might not need to (since during authentication you don't know if you trigger the admin controller)
2. Defining a policy for each logical role is not a bad idea. Policies tend to change over time, e.g. a policy named "Admin" may have more conditions (e.g. you may decide that jon.doe@testuser.com to automatically granted admin permissions). By using the same policy name, any change will automatically apply to all your endpoints/controllers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me to understand the mecanic. I tried to use your approach but I was not able tu use userManager in ConfigureServices(...) of Startup.cs yet.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083989/dependency-injection-on-authorization-policy