# How to check if a User is in a single role? Using Identity in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

How do I check if the current user is in a single role?

In my app I can have an user with multiple roles, but, some roles like `Role1`, have specific behaviors.
How do I isolate the specific behavior from `Role1` when a user have two roles(`Role1` and `Role2`)?
If the user is in `Role2` then they should have another behavior, even if they are in `Role1` as well.

The solution I came up with was

```
if (User.IsInRole(Role1.ToString()) && !User.IsInRole(Role2.ToString()))
{
   //implementation
}
```

Is there another way to do this? Maybe using policies?

Comment: IMHO, you should code to rights (or) permissions (or) "claims".  It is shortsighted and hard to maintain code written to roles.  Consider : https://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/rant-hard-coded-security-roles/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I check if the current user is in a single role?

After user login successfully, you could use  the [UserManager.GetRoleAsync() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to get a list of role names the specified user belongs to. Then, based on the result to check whether the user is in a single Role.

```
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email).Result;
                var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.ToArray();
                // then, based on the roles array to check if the current user is in a single role.

                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

> How do I isolate the specific behavior from Role1 when a user have two
> roles(Role1 and Role2)? If the user is in Role2 then they should have
> another behavior, even if they are in Role1 as well. Is there another way to do this? Maybe using policies?

Yes, Policy-based authorization is a good choice. For example, in my sample, there have 3 kinds of Roles: Admin, Manager and User.

We could create the following policies in the Startup.cs file,

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("readpolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager", "User"));
            options.AddPolicy("writepolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager"));
        });
```

Then, we will apply these policies to the Role controller, as below:

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "readpolicy")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var roles = roleManager.Roles.ToList();
        return View(roles);
    }
    [Authorize(Policy = "writepolicy")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new IdentityRole());
    }
```

Now, we can based on the policy to call the action method.

Reference:

[Adding Role Authorization to a ASP.NET MVC Core Application](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-role-authorization-to-a-asp-net-mvc-core-application/)

[Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, but it was helpful to me when I was coding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a policy it is the best aproach to your case.
Create a policy that uses RequireAssertion in builder

Se this post: [Role based authorization in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Identity and ExternalLogin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216973/role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core-3-1-with-identity-and-externallogin)

Comment: Got a link or some more info on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was creating a method that check if the user was in **any** of the roles:

```
    public async Task<bool> IsInAnyRoleAsync(TUser user, RoleEnum[] roles)
    {
        var userIsInRole = new List<bool>();
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var roleName = Enum.GetName(role.GetType(), role);
            userIsInRole.Add(await IsInRoleAsync(user, roleName));
        }

        return userIsInRole.Any(isInRole => isInRole == true);
    }
```