# How to clear cacheKey in separate instance of IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm running on `ASP.NET Core 1.1` where in my `Startup.cs` I configure Policies, as well as `DistributedMemoryCache`, like this:

```
var roleRepo = new RoleRepo(Configuration, new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions()));

services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MyPolicyRoleRequirement(roleRepo)));
});

services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

//...

services.AddTransient<IRoleRepo, RoleRepo>();
```

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to remove a specific cacheKey for a specific user. When the user gets added to a new role, I then try to remove the existing cache entry for that cacheKey (username plus rolename), and then re-add with the updated "isInRole" value. But when my controller that removes, then adds the new cacheKey checks to see if the query exists, it always returns null. Then, if I try to navigate to the page that checks whether the user is in the role or not, that check still shows the PREVIOUS value of the cacheKey.

What I believe is going on is that since my policies get passed a single instance of my `RoleRepo` (which injects `IMemoryCache`), it ends up being a separate instance vs the one that is DI'd in the `services.AddTransient` line.

How do I configure this so either the `IMemoryCache` is a singleton, or specifically pass the SAME instance of my `RoleRepo` into the `services.AddTransient` line?

Here's my `RoleRepo setup:

```
private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

public RoleRepo(IConfigurationRoot configuration, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    : base(configuration)
{
    _memoryCache = memoryCache;
}
```

Comment: See the method here: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/aabe8c34a62786c313e20125d70b36d3c5e72a75/src/Caching/Memory/src/MemoryCacheServiceCollectionExtensions.cs and you will see that if succeed it is added as Singleton. Other than that from the code you showed - only guesses can be made. Can you add the code that interacts with cache as well ?

Comment: Whats the point of having a transient memory cache? This would just create multiple instances of the cache, which kinda makes it useless since every request, even every resolve would access a different instance of it. the only value of memory cache is if its a singleton and survives the requests

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue. Since I'm "newing-up" my RoleRepo, I just went ahead and added THAT INSTANCE as a singleton...

```
services.AddSingleton<IRoleRepo>(roleRepo);
```